# Can an outer automorphism fix the center of a group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, group-isomorphism

I have just learned about inner and outer automorphisms, and I'm having a hard time visualizing the outer automorphism as quotient classes. Since the inner automorphisms fix the center, does it mean that any automorphism that fixes the center is necessarily an inner automorphism?

Comment: What do you mean by " visualizing the outer automorphism as quotient classes"? An automorphism isn't a quotient.

Comment: @NoahSchweber, I think the OP calls "outer automorphisms" the elements of $Aut(G)/Inn(G)$.

Comment: It is also not obvious what you mean exactly by automorphisms fixing the centre of the group. Do you mean that they fix every element of the centre (which is the standard usage when talking about automorphisms of fields in Galois theory), or do you mean that they map the centre to itself as a set?

Comment: You seem to mix up two non-equivalent definitions (1) outer automorphism = automorphism modulo inner automorphism (2) outer automorphism = automorphism that is not inner. It's not the same. I'll avoid (2) which I view as a confusing abuse of terminology. An outer automorphism of $G$ then doesn't act on $G$; still acts on $Z(G)$ (i.e. the Aut$(G)$ action on $Z(G)$ factors thru Out$(G)$. The action of $\mathrm{Out}(G)$ on $Z(G)$ is not always faithful. For instance if $Z(G)=1$ while $\mathrm{Out}(G)\neq 1$ it's not faithful, and there are many other examples (eg the quaternion group of order 8).

Answer (score 3):

No, this is not the case: we can have an automorphism of a group which is not an inner automorphism but which nonetheless fixes the center pointwise - even when the center is nontrivial.

*(As Mark Bennet observes, by contrast every automorphism whatsoever fixes the center in the weak sense that it restricts to a self-bijection of the center, but pointwise-fixing is more complicated. In particular, any nontrivial automorphism of an abelian group does not fix the center - which is after all the whole group - pointwise.)*

For example, let $G$ be a group with trivial center which has some automorphism $\alpha$ which is not inner, and let $A$ be any nontrivial abelian group. Consider the group $G\times A$. The center of $G\times A$ is exactly the image of the map $A\rightarrow G\times A: a\mapsto (e_G, a)$ and so is nontrivial, and the automorphism defined by $$\hat{\alpha}: G\times A\rightarrow G\times A: (g,a)\mapsto (\alpha(g),a)$$ fixes that center. However, $\hat{\alpha}$ is not an inner automorphism of $G\times A$ since $\alpha$ wasn't an inner automorphism of $G$.

Comment: Of course where the centre is trivial it is fixed pointwise (likewise if the centre is cyclic of order $2$). One interesting example is $S_6$ - the symmetric group on six objects, which has a non-trivial outer-automorphism and a trivial centre: simply noted because sometimes concrete examples are helpful.

Comment: @MarkBennet Good point, I've edited to explicitly say that I'm giving a way of constructing examples with nontrivial centers.

Answer (score 0):

The centre is a characteristic subgroup, and is fixed by all automorphisms. That in itself is pretty much a tautology. But note the fact that the centre has a unique definition/property, even though there may be other subgroups isomorphic to the centre as abstract groups. And that is a property preserved by homomorphism.

Note therefore that the image of the centre of a group under any homomorphism must be commutative and contained within the centre of the image, and it is easy to show from this that an automorphism must fix the centre. Note further that this does not mean that an automorphism necessarily fixes the individual elements of the centre.

Comment: It does leave the question of whether an automorphism that fixes the center *pointwise* is inner (still no).

Comment: @Servaes Thanks for that useful comment.

Comment: @Servaes I've added a bit to my answer to address this.

Comment: You're writing "fix" the center to mean "stabilize" or "leaves invariant". I think "fix" (and "fixator") was a terminology that was precisely introduced to mean "pointwise stabilize".

Comment: @YCor What I mean by "fix" here is that the centre is mapped isomorphically to itself - I make it clear I don't mean pointwise fixed because terminology can vary and carry ambiguities and people use the words differently.

Comment: Yes you made it clear, I'm just pointing out that I believe it's not an optimal choice of terminology.